# Team Foundation Server Licensing for Local TFS Development

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am currently working on developing a custom Project Template in Team Foundation Server (TFS) and have been working on build and tweaking it over the course of several months.  My preferred method is to test my template changes on a locally installed trial version and then once it all works I send it out to the live server.  This morning my trial version expired, so I no longer have a safety net.

Is anyone aware of a 'free' license that I can use for such a case?  I am the only one accessing it and only using test data so I can prove that transitions and constraints are working.  It seems impossible to search Google for this information since the terms are all conflated with the primary focus of TFS.

There are multiple teams with lots of developers depending on the live TFS server for daily work, so I prefer not to send live changes out since even borking it for a few minutes costs lots of money in dev effort.

Thanks for any and all ideas!

Comment: What's about a TFS Express? Is it not free-of-charge?

Comment: CodePlex has an option to used to the TFS functionality within VS, of course, that functionality isn't found in the free versions of VS from what i remember

Comment: I'll give the TFS express a shot--I feel like early on I looked into it and felt like it might not give me all the abilities I needed, but now that I'm this far in I might be able to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can extend the trial from the [TFS admin console](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/05/07/extending-trials-of-tfs-2010.aspx) if TFS express doesn't meet your needs. The link is for 2010, but I've done it in 2013 as well.